# Resign app with Distribution Provision

Tags: ios, jenkins

Currently I have a distribution provision setup on my laptop to distribute enterprise app once compiled, however I wanted to get this process into Jenkins as well.

One of my concerns of doing such is so:

1) Do I need a new certificate for another computer and go through the entire process of creating a provision profile for that PC along, or can I use the current provision and have it signed with the application on different pc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to export your certificate from keychain and install it on the PC you wish to build from. right click the development or distribution certificate -> export and choose .p12 and then choose a password(if you want to). You can then install that on your jenkins machine and it is giving that machine the same signing authority as your base computer where you originally made the certificate and put your profiles on there as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @rootser117, that is what i needed. Will give a shot today and see if it works.

Comment: This link is kind of off topic but shows how to export a certificate. [link] https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started:+iOS:+PushI feel your pain on the set up of this stuff but once you get Jenkins going its a great tool and worth the struggle

Comment: yes definitely, its a one time struggle but totally worth it.